# IOS 8 iPad make only Launch Screen portrait only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I know how to make an iPad app portrait only for the whole app and how to make particular views portrait only, but not how to make the launch image portrait only. How do I do it?

Currently I only have "portrait" checked under "iOS 7.0 and Later" in images.xcassets. The reason I want the launch image portrait only is I tried getting landscape to work but despite multiple attempts and asking about it here, I had no luck.

Clarification:
I want the app to handle both portrait and landscape iPad and iPhone. But the landscape image for iPad does not display so I want to force the launch image and just the launch image to be Portrait only.

Comment: If your app is portrait only, it will launch in portrait and the problem won't arise. So what's the actual problem?

Comment: I want my app to handle both portrait and landscape for iPhone and iPad. However the launch screen for iPad shows only black when launching landscape.

Answer (score 6):

No idea if you checked this but here is something often overlooked.

In the Workspace, if you choose your target project, in **Deployment Info**, there are two things to check there. First, make sure the **Device Orientation** is set to "**Portrait**" only. Then, open the drop down menu on "**Devices**". Choose **each** separately and do the same thing. For some reason for me, universal does't apply it to **iPhone** and **iPad** simultaneously.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but no luck unfortunately. See my OP for a clarification

Comment: you are my hero! saved me an hour. :)