# How to make Launch Screen only portrait not support other orientations

Tags: ios, ios11, launch-screen

I need set launch screen only portrait but in other view controller that can support all orientation.Firstly, I try this method: 
[IOS 8 iPad make only Launch Screen portrait only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017181/ios-8-ipad-make-only-launch-screen-portrait-only)
but it can't make other view controllers that support all orientations.
How can i do something to fix it?

Comment: are you talking about the actual launch screen? Or the first ViewController that you consider as a transitionnal launch screen?

Comment: yes, it's the actual launch screen from xib.

Comment: Have a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756091/ios-disabling-landscape-launchscreen-storyboard